# Angular Parent component listen to multiple inputs in child component

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-components

I have a parent and child component that renders multiple inputs. Each set of inputs is inside an array. I'm looping the array and trying to display/update the current values. I'm struggling with the parent being able to read the data in the child component. Outputting `{{f.value|json}}` just shows a bunch of empty objects with nothing inside of it.

I've looked around at all the `@Outputs` that are mentioned in other questions but they all seem to relate to button clicks. How can I listen to multiple inputs inside the child?

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Group } from './model/group';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-item',
  template: `
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" [ngModel]="group.name">
    <label>Login:</label><input type="text" name="login" [ngModel]="group.login">
    <label>Address:</label><input type="text" name="address" [ngModel]="group.address">
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() group: Group;
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Group } from './model/group';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-groups',
  template: `
    <form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f)">
      <div *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index;">
        <div ngModelGroup="{{i}}">
          <app-list-item [group]="group"></app-list-item>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{f.value|json}}
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="f.invalid">save</button>
    </form>
  `
})

export class ParentComponent {

  public groups: Group[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGroups();
  }

  getGroups(): void {
    this.groups = [
      {id: 1, name: "john", login: "john", "address": "123 main street"},
      {id: 2, name: "mark", login: "mark", "address": "23 main street"},
      {id: 3, name: "james", login: "james", "address": "44 main street"},
      {id: 4, name: "hayley", login: "hayley", "address": "55 main street"}
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: From what I've seen ... the ngForm data structure does not recognize any child components. I'd assume that is why the parent `f.value` sees no data. I've heard some developers had success with passing in the ngForm itself into the child so it can work with it. I'll see if I can find an example.

Comment: Here is an article that covers a technique for doing this:https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664 but note that it is using reactive forms, not template-driven forms.

Comment: '...all the @Outputs that are mentioned in other questions but they all seem to relate to button clicks' - Actually you can emit your outputs on any async event (event inside the setinterval method :) ). So in your case - you simple can add `(input)="..." on your input and inside this method just emit an event to parent component. 
But I think - using template-driven forms is not a good choice for you task (agreed with @DeborahK)